# Outlook does not render html content

Tags: c#-4.0, html-email, outlook-2010

I have following email message.

[image]

after running the following code

```
   string pattern = "<img src=\"cid.*?</span></p>|Inline image 1.*?</FONT>";

        Outlook.Selection mySelection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
        Outlook.MailItem mailitem = null;

        foreach (Object obj in mySelection)
        {
            if (obj is Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                mailitem = (Outlook.MailItem)obj;                                    
                string body = mailitem.HTMLBody;
                Regex reg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline|RegexOptions.Singleline);
                MatchCollection matchs = reg.Matches(body);
                    foreach(Match match in matchs)
                    {
                        string a = match.Groups[0].Value;
                        mailitem.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
                        mailitem.Body = body.Replace(a, string.Empty);                            
                        mailitem.Save();
                    }
                    //mailitem.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain;
            }
        }
```

I got following email message in outlook .
[image]

The body text works in browser. It means when i saved the body text in simple html file it works properly and display original message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change body format string.

```
 foreach(Match match in matchs)
                {
                    string a = match.Groups[0].Value;
                    mailitem.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
                    mailitem.HTMLBody = body.Replace(a, string.Empty);                            
                    mailitem.Save();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,[\n\r and < /br> tags are will not work here insted of that need to use < br > ]

Example code:

> ```
>     public void OpenOutlook()
>     {
>         try
>         {
>
>             Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
>             Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
>
>             oMsg.Subject = "emailSubject";
>             oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
>             oMsg.BCC = "emailBcc";
>             oMsg.To = "emailRecipient";
>
>             string body = "emailMessage";
>             //if body contains \n\r replace that into <br>
>             body = body.Replace("\r\n", "<br>");
>             body = body.Replace("\n", "<br>");
>
>             oMsg.HTMLBody = body;
>
>             oMsg.Display(true); 
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             throw ex;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score -2):

```
mailitem.HTMLBody = body;
```

will do the trick.